# Java 8 Streams to filter by average greater than oldest element

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream, deque

I am trying to filter a bunch of `person`'s in a city such that average of their ages is greater than the age of the person who has the oldest `created_at` timestamp in the database.

I am doing something like the below,

```
LinkedBlockingDeque<Person> allAges = null;
LinkedBlockingDeque<Person> filteredAges = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Person>();

allAges = ageStorage.getAllAgesByCityOrderByInsertionTime("city A");

allAges.stream()
       .filter(this.getFirstInsertedAgeGreaterThanAverage(allAges))
       .forEach(filteredAges::add);
```

And the `getFirstInsertedAgeGreaterThanAverage` is as follows,

```
private static Predicate<Integer> getFirstInsertedAgeGreaterThanAverage(LinkedBlockingDeque<Person> personList){
    return p -> (personList.stream().mapToInt(Person::getAge).average() >
     personList.peekFirst().getAge());
}
```

I guess there is something not so right here but not sure what...Is there a way this could be done without the `getFirstInsertedAgeGreaterThanAverage` method

Comment: There could be multiple solutions to that. Which one do you want to keep?

Comment: If you want the largest such subset, sort the persons by their age and add persons to the set, starting with the oldest until the average is just above the age of that other person.

Comment: Also, does it have to use streams? Using a regular old for loop and some helper variables might be much easier here.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a trick question? It is impossible to have an average bigger than the maximum. The biggest average you can ever get is the exactly the maximum, by selecting the maximum/oldest element itself (and only that). Or perhaps all elements having the same age as the oldest, if there are multiple. Selecting anything else will always have a smaller average, of course.

Comment: @Tunaki I would just prefer not to use two `stream()` and trying to see if I can do it with one

@tobias_k I know it could be done in different ways, we won't even need code for this while SQL could do that.. please consider it as a learning process 

@Holger No, not a trick question.. I just want to see in a bunch of numbers if the average is greater than the earliest inserted number ..

Comment: Selecting a group of persons who have an average age older than an arbitrary age isn't meaningful, since any arbitrary number of combinations could match so long as you include enough people with high ages. The resulting set could be different each time even if the source set hasn't changed.

Comment: @g0c00l.g33k if the task is to return whether or not the average of a collection's ages is greater than the first inserted person's age, that's a different kettle of fish.Your `Predicate<Person>` code as written is returning the same result for every element, since it's not checking any value of the `Person p->` that you passed into the predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question which exactly subset you want. Including only one person with the maximal age (or nothing if it happens to be the first one) is the a valid answer. So I assume that you want to get the maximal possible such subset. As @tobias_k noticed, this could be solved sorting the input by age, decreasing, and select the longest prefix for which the average do not exceed the limit.

Unfortunately this cannot be solved in single Stream using standard Stream API. A possible solution might look like this:

```
public static List<Person> maxSubSetWithGreaterAverage(Collection<Person> persons,
        int averageLimit) {
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>(persons);
    // Sort people by age, decreasing
    list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed());
    // get all the ages
    int[] ages = list.stream().mapToInt(Person::getAge).toArray();
    // transform them to cumulative sums
    Arrays.parallelPrefix(ages, Integer::sum);
    // Find the longest prefix for which the cumulative sum is bigger
    // than average
    int length = IntStream.range(0, ages.length)
            .filter(count -> ages[count] <= averageLimit * (count + 1)).findFirst()
            .orElse(ages.length);
    // return the corresponding subList
    return list.subList(0, length);
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Person> filtered = maxSubSetWithGreaterAverage(allAges, 
            allAges.peekFirst().getAge());
```

However without using Stream API and `parallelPrefix` the solution looks better, works faster and eats less memory:

```
public static List<Person> maxSubSetWithGreaterAverage(Collection<Person> persons,
        int averageLimit) {
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>(persons);
    list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed());
    int cumulativeAge = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        cumulativeAge += list.get(i).getAge();
        if(cumulativeAge <= averageLimit * (i + 1) )
            return list.subList(0, i);
    }
    return list;
}
```

---

Using my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/) library it's possible to define custom intermediate operation which will perform the necessary filtering in single Stream, though this requires advanced magic:

```
public static <T> UnaryOperator<StreamEx<T>> takeWhileAverageGreater(
        ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor, int averageLimit) {
    return s -> takeWhileAverageGreater(
            s.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(keyExtractor).reversed()),
            keyExtractor, 0L, 0L, averageLimit);
}

private static <T> StreamEx<T> takeWhileAverageGreater(StreamEx<T> input,
        ToIntFunction<? super T> keyExtractor, long count, long cumulativeSum,
        int averageLimit) {
    return input.headTail((head, tail) -> {
        // head is the first element, tail is the Stream of the rest
        // update current sum
        long newSum = cumulativeSum + keyExtractor.applyAsInt(head);
        // short-circuit via null if the limit is reached
        // otherwise call myself for the tail prepending with head
        return newSum <= averageLimit * (count + 1) ? null :
           takeWhileAverageGreater(tail, keyExtractor, count + 1, newSum, averageLimit)
               .prepend(head);
    });
}
```

Now new `takeWhileAverageGreater` operation can be used like this:

```
List<Person> filtered = StreamEx.of(allAges)
        .chain(takeWhileAverageGreater(Person::getAge, allAges.peekFirst().getAge()))
        .toList();
```

The result is the same.